# not true * not true equals true?

Tags: r, logical-operators

I am having some problems in my code because of the following behaviour of `R`:

```
> F * F
[1] 0

> !T * !T
[1] TRUE
```

Can somebody explain me how to avoid this?

I need to multiply some values and get the result of a logical multiplication:

```
!first * !second * !third
```

And I would like to get a "True" only if all the values are true.

Comment: (a) `T`  /  `F` is a _bad_ R habit to get into (ref: https://github.com/ironholds/jammr). (b) use `(` `)` i.e.  `(!TRUE) & (!TRUE)`

Comment: Agree w/ hrbrmstr:  use a few extra parentheses;  much easier than remembering all operator precedences -- not to mention **far** easier when debugging later on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a matter of precedence of the operators. The negation `!` has a lower precedence than the multiplication. 
A list, in descending order of the operator precedence, is given [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html). This list can also be displayed with `?Syntax`.

If the negations of `TRUE` are put into braces, one obtains a result that is more intuitively clear:

```
(!TRUE) * (!TRUE)
[1] 0
```

In this case, each instance of `(!TRUE)` is coerced into 0 by the multiplication, and the result is obviously 0.

However, the operation `!TRUE * !TRUE` is equal to `!(TRUE * !TRUE)` which in turn is equal to `!0`, and, hence (with the negation coercing the zero into a logical `FALSE`), the result is equal to `TRUE`.

To summarize, paraphrasing the title of your question, one could state:

NOT(TRUE * NOT(TRUE)) equals to TRUE.